# Installing Yapsy for Python script in Windows

Tags: python, python-2.7

Im trying to run a script in python 2.7 but I need Yapsy, I download from github but I dont know how to install it, I cant find any documentation in github neither in [sourceforge](http://yapsy.sourceforge.net/)[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [manual](https://yapsy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):
`pip install -e "git+https://github.com/tibonihoo/yapsy.git#egg=yapsy&subdirectory=package"` or

`pip install -e "hg+http://hg.code.sf.net/p/yapsy/code#egg=yapsy&subdirectory=package"`

Comment: Also the usual `pip install yapsy` should work to get the "official" release (the commands indicated in the manual are to get the development version).